# How does template.ParseGlob behave if files aren't compatible

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a question in relation to the below line of code:

```
ts, err = ts.ParseGlob("./templates/*.layout.tmpl")
```

Where ts is a specific page such as:

```
{{template "base" .}}

{{define "content"}}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h1>This is the about page</h1>
                <p>This is a paragraph of text</p>
                <p>This is a paragraph of text</p>

                <p>This came from the template: {{index .StringMap "test"}}</p>

                <p>
                    {{if ne (index .StringMap "remote_ip") ""}}
                        Your remote ip address is {{index .StringMap "remote_ip"}}
                    {{else}}
                        I don't know your ip address yet. Visit the <a href="/">home page</a> so I can set it.
                    {{end}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{end}}
```

I'm wondering what would happen if there's a page base.layout.template found but it's defined something other than base in the actual file so it might look like this:

```
{{define "not_base"}}
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
              crossorigin="anonymous">

        {{block "css" .}}

        {{end}}
    </head>
    <body>

    {{block "content" .}}

    {{end}}


    {{block "js" .}}

    {{end}}

    </body>
    </html>
{{end}}
```

What I suppose I'm asking is will the pages not parse because parsing is dependent on there being a line {{define "base"}} and not {{define "not_base"}}?

Comment: It will *parse* just fine, you can check the returned error to confirm. However, keep in mind that, trying to *execute* a template that contains the `{{ template "base" . }}` action, while the `*template.Template` object does not have a template with that name registered, will fail with an error. You can also confirm that yourself by checking the error returned from `ts.Execute` or `ts.ExecuteTemplate`.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for the comment, could you clarify what parse does exactly. I was confusing it with execute I think.

Comment: The `ParseXxx` functions parse the files, looking for template *actions*, and ensuring their syntax is correct, and producing a [`parse.Tree`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template/parse#Tree). The parse tree is then used by the template object during execution.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/rR7z7BnpbiC -- You can see, that the code never defines foo, bar, baz templates but you can still "mention" them, the parser don't care. However, were you to execute the result of that it would return an error. Compare to that the template with invalid syntax, it fails immediately during parsing.